# When I trying to Click on Paired device list of bluetooth then it will unfortunately , MyApp has stopped message display and my application is closed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

When I click on paired device list of Bluetooth, application crashes , and I get a message saying 'MyApp has stopped
When I start my application first time it doesn't show my Paired devices in paired devices list but when i switch off  the display and switch it on again it shows.

```
package com.example.bluetoothapp;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ListView listViewPaired;
    ListView listViewDetected;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    Button buttonSearch, buttonOn, buttonDesc, buttonOff;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter, detectedAdapter;
    static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    BluetoothClass bdClass;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    private ButtonClicked clicked;
    ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
        listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
        buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff);
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        clicked = new ButtonClicked();
        handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        /*
         * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth
         * devices; this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
         */
        listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
        listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) arg1;
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "" + txt.getText().toString(), 1000).show();

            }
        });
    }

    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevice.size() > 0) {

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice) {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                        + device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }

        }

    }

    class ListItemClicked implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            // bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            Log.i("Log", "The dvice : " + bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we
             * can directly call the connect(). but for the safer side we must
             * usethe threading object.
             */
            // callThread();
            // connect(bdDevice);
            Boolean isBonded = false;
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                if (isBonded) {
                    // arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());

                    getPairedDevices();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }// connect(bdDevice);
            Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: " + isBonded);
        }
    }

    class ListItemClickedonPaired implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            bdDevice = arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            try {
                Boolean removeBonding = removeBond(bdDevice);
                if (removeBonding) {
                    arrayListpaired.remove(position);

                }

                Log.i("Log", "Removed" + removeBonding);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * private void callThread() { new Thread(){ public void run() { Boolean
     * isBonded = false; try { isBonded = createBond(bdDevice); if(isBonded) {
     * arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
     * adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } } catch (Exception e) { // TODO
     * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }//connect(bdDevice);
     * Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded); } }.start(); }
     */
    private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) {
        Boolean bool = false;
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
            Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Class[] par = {};
            Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
            Object[] args = {};
            bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);// , args);// this invoke
                                                        // creates the detected
                                                        // devices paired.
            // Log.i("Log", "This is: "+bool.booleanValue());
            // Log.i("Log", "devicesss: "+bdDevice.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bool.booleanValue();
    };

    public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice) throws Exception {
        Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
        return returnValue.booleanValue();
    }

    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice) throws Exception {
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);
        return returnValue.booleanValue();
    }

    class ButtonClicked implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOn:
                onBluetooth();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                startSearching();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDesc:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonOff:
                offBluetooth();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                try {
                    // device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation",
                    // boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    // device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput",
                    // boolean.class).invoke(device);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (arrayListBluetoothDevices.size() < 1) // this checks if the
                                                            // size of bluetooth
                                                            // device is 0,then
                                                            // add the
                { // device to the arraylist.
                    detectedAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                            + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);

                } else {
                    boolean flag = true; // flag to indicate that particular
                                            // device is already in the arlist
                                            // or not
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayListBluetoothDevices.size(); i++) {
                        if (device.getAddress().equals(
                                arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress())) {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (flag == true) {
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n"
                                + device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
                BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        MainActivity.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    private void onBluetooth() {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");
        }
    }

    private void offBluetooth() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }

    private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(
                BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }

    class HandleSeacrh extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 111:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack.

Comment: 07-29 10:20:48.867: E/AndroidRuntime(6641): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-29 10:20:48.867: E/AndroidRuntime(6641):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
07-29 10:20:48.867: E/AndroidRuntime(6641):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
07-29 10:20:48.867: E/AndroidRuntime(6641):  at com.example.bluetoothapp.MainActivity$ListItemClicked.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:123)